# Having trouble introducing a constant matrix to multiplication in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to implement a layer that is **not** fully connected. I have a matrix that specifies the connectivity I desire in the variable `connectivity_matrix`, which is a numpy array of ones and zeros.

The way I am currently trying to impliment the layer is by pairwise multiplying the weights, by this connectivity matrix `F`:

[image]

Is this the correct way to do this in tensorflow? Here is what I have so far

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

num_input = 10
num_layer1 = 313
num_output = 700

# For example:
connectivity_matrix = np.array(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(num_layer1, num_output)), dtype='float32')

input = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, num_input])

# Here is where I specify the connectivity in tensorflow
connectivity = tf.constant(connectivity_matrix, shape=[num_layer1, num_output])

# One basic, fully connected layer
layer1 = tflearn.fully_connected(input, num_layer1, activation='relu')

# Here is where I want to have a non-fully connected layer
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([num_layer1, num_output]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_output]))
# so take a fully connected W, and do a pairwise multiplication with my tf_connectivity matrix
W_filtered = tf.mul(connectivity, W)
output = tf.matmul(layer1, W_filtered) + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Masking out unwanted connections in each iteration should work, but I am not sure what the convergence properties are like. It may okay for a small enough learning rate?

Another approach would be to penalize unwanted weights in the cost function. You would use a mask matrix with 1's at unwanted connections, and 0's at wanted ones (or have a smoother transition). This would be multiplied by weights, squared/scaled and added to the cost function. This should converge more smoothly.

P.S.: If you've made progress on this, it would be great to hear your comments as I am also working on this problem.

Comment: The method I used above worked well for my purposes. However I have not made any further progress